# ¿La carpeta de migraciones se sube a github?

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo una duda sobre lo que estoy subiendo a github, es precisamente de la carpeta migraciones, ¿esa carpeta se sube?

Estoy hablando de esta carpeta:

> myapp/migrations

Comment: Si, es importante para que le de la estructura adecuada a la base de datos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La documentación de Django dice

> The migration files for each app live in a “migrations” directory inside of that app, and are designed to be committed to, and distributed as part of, its codebase. You should be making them once on your development machine and then running the same migrations on your colleagues’ machines, your staging machines, and eventually your production machines.

(No soy un experto en ingles pero entiendo algo)

La carpeta y los archivos contenidos en Migration estan diseñados para distribuir y componer el codigo base de tu app, desde la fase de desarrollo, pasando por desarrollo de otras personas de tu equipo (versionamiento y repositorios) y tambien en produccion debe estar presente.